# Activate cell in column A on next empty row in a Google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to activate the cell in column A of the next empty row in my Google sheet.

I have created the below script based on a video of youtube - this does return the value of the next empty row but I am struggling on how to activate the selection.

Can anyone help on this please?

```
function jumpToLastRowChilled() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Chilled Sheet");

  var rng = ss.getRange("A1:H").getValues();
  var lrIndex;

  for(var i = rng.length-1;i>=0;i--){
    lrIndex = i;

    if(!rng[i].every(function(c){ return c == ""})){
      break;
    }
  }  
    var lr = lrIndex + 2;

}
```

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your goal, for example, when you want to activate the row of `var lr = lrIndex + 2` at the column "A", how about putting `ss.getRange(lr, 1).activate()` to the last line of the function of `jumpToLastRowChilled()`? If my understanding is not correct, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found to do this you can do the below:

```js
function jumpToLastRowChilled() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Chilled Sheet");
  var rng = ss.getDataRange();
  var lr = rng.getLastRow();
  var alr = ss.getRange(lr+1,1).activate();
}
```